# S3 uploads from Java SDK much slower than AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Uploading a relatively small file (15 MB) is much slower when uploading with Java SDK when compared with AWS CLI, holding everything constant: same laptop, same AWS account, same region.

My code follows more or less same basic pattern as [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html)

```java
// inputStream is ByteArrayInputStream, all in memory 
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentType("text/plain");
metadata.setContentLength(contentLength);

PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3keyName, inputStream, metadata);
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
s3Client.putObject(request);
```

Performance disparity:

- AWS CLI (`aws s3 cp ...`)  takes about 15 seconds
- Java SDK takes over a minute

Comment: note that file in question is relatively small

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried several different options.  I even generated a presigned URL and used curl but for me, with a 15MB file everything was taking about 15-16 seconds while the CLI was taking 9.  As @Mark B indicated though TransferManager was the key.  Starting with [this code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileJava.html), but telling the code how much threading I wanted via `withMultipartUploadThreshold` got me down to about 6.5 seconds.

Note three things:

1. I am letting the library read a file.  When I used a ByteArrayInputStream the program didn't seem to multi-thread and I was still at 15 seconds.  Letting the AWS libraries read the file seems to have let the program split up the file itself.
2. `withMultipartUploadThreshold` is tricky.  If I gave it 15MB there was no improvement.  If I gave it 5MB there was no improvement.  But at 1MB there was a significant improvement.  I did not figure out where the lower threshold is though.
3. I'm not setting the content-type.  That would have to be done in a separate S3 call.

I have 4 other examples that don't work very well if you'd like too.

```
public class HighLevelMultipartUpload {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Regions clientRegion = Regions.US_EAST_2;
        String bucketName = "<my-bucket>";
        String fileObjKeyName = "file.txt";
        String fileName = "/tmp/file.txt";

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // this made it slower
        // String fileContent = Files.readString(Path.of(fileName));

        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();
            TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withMultipartUploadThreshold(1024L*1024)
                    .withS3Client(s3Client)
                    .build();

            // TransferManager processes all transfers asynchronously,
            // so this call returns immediately.
            Upload upload = tm.upload(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, new File(fileName));

            // used if using the file and supplying metadata
            // Upload upload = tm.upload(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes()), metadata);
            System.out.println("Object upload started");

            // Optionally, wait for the upload to finish before continuing.
            upload.waitForCompletion();
            System.out.println("Object upload complete");
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println( "run took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction.  The key was to use `TransferManager` with a File, not InputStream.  Playing with `withMultipartUploadThreshold` or `withExecutorFactory` had no effect.

Comment: What's especially frustrating: I *had* thought to try using a File instead of an InputStream, but only tried it with `AmazonS3.putObject`, where it didn't help.

Comment: So @wrschneider - one might argue that it is the correct answer then?  :)

Comment: We are using TransferManager to upload files continuously for 24 hours. The speed is very fast initially but with time the upload speed gets slower and slower.

Answer (score 3):

The CLI tool is making a best effort to utilize multi-part upload to achieve the fastest upload performance. You can achieve similar performance in Java by utilizing the [TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) class instead of the `AmazonS3Client` class.

Note that this has not yet been implemented in the AWS SDK for Java version 2.0. At this time it is still [under development](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/37).

Comment: Nope, switched to `transferManager.upload` and got exactly same results as with `putObject`.  Is there some config setting I'm missing for increasing buffer size or number of threads?

Comment: Did you configure TransferManager with an `ExecutorService`?

Comment: tried that too: `withExecutorFactory(factory)` where `factory.newExecutor` returns `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)`.  No impact.

Comment: You might have to play with the `multipartUploadThreshold` and `minimumUploadPartSize` to get performance similar to the AWS CLI tool. I can't find any documentation on what the CLI tool uses for those settings.

Answer (score 0):

AWS CLI actually uses boto (Python SDK) itself and not Java SDK.

`aws s3 sync` is faster than `aws s3 cp` and `aws s3 cp` is faster than AWS Java SDK as AWS CLI uses multi-threading to copy multiple files simultaneously to make the copy operation faster.

**Using AWS SDK for Java**

You can achieve the similar behaviour using `TransferManager` for Amazon S3 Operations.

Below is the sample code snippet:

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.MultipleFileUpload;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManagerBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.Upload;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

File f = new File(file_path);
TransferManager xfer_mgr = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().build();
try {
    Upload xfer = xfer_mgr.upload(bucket_name, key_name, f)
    // loop with Transfer.isDone()
    XferMgrProgress.showTransferProgress(xfer);
    //  or block with Transfer.waitForCompletion()
    XferMgrProgress.waitForCompletion(xfer);
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}
xfer_mgr.shutdownNow();
```

Here are the references from AWS Documentation:

- [Using TransferManager for Amazon S3 Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html#transfermanager-upload-file)
- [Class TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html)

**Using AWS SDK for JavaScript:**

You can achieve the similar behaviour using `upload` method.

`upload(params = {}, [options], [callback]) ⇒ AWS.S3.ManagedUpload`

> Uploads an arbitrarily sized buffer, blob, or stream, using intelligent concurrent handling of parts if the payload is large enough. You can configure the concurrent queue size by setting `options`. Note that this is the only operation for which the SDK can retry requests with stream bodies.

**Examples:**

**- Uploading a stream object**

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream};
s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

**- Uploading a stream with concurrency of 1 and partSize of 10mb**

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream};
var options = {partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1};
s3.upload(params, options, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

In the second example, you can see the `queueSize` that defines concurrency to achieve parallelism.

Comment: This looks like Javascript - I'm looking for Java

Comment: @wrschneider I have updated the answer. I think we cannot make S3 file upload any faster in case of Java.

Answer (score 0):

- AWS cli is using native calls( boto python) which are going to be a bit faster
- Also when using aws cli we are already established the client connection(so the call is raw here to s3) and we are calculating only the time required for upload here not the connection to the client as we do in java.
- To copy an Amazon S3 object that is larger than 5 GB with the AWS SDK for Java, use the low-level Java API.

  **To copy an object using the low-level Java API, do the following (multipart upload )**
- Initiate a multipart upload by executing the `AmazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload()` method.
- Save the upload ID from the response object that the `AmazonS3Client.initiateMultipartUpload()` method returns. You provide this upload ID for each part-upload operation.
- Copy all of the parts. For each part that you need to copy, create a new instance of the `CopyPartRequest` class. Provide the part information, including the source and destination bucket names, source and destination object keys, upload ID, locations of the first and last bytes of the part, and part number.
- Save the responses of the `AmazonS3Client.copyPart()` method calls. Each response includes the ETag value and part number for the uploaded part. You need this information to complete the multipart upload.
- Call the `AmazonS3Client.completeMultipartUpload()` method to complete the copy operation.

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LowLevelMultipartCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Regions clientRegion = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION;
        String sourceBucketName = "*** Source bucket name ***";
        String sourceObjectKey = "*** Source object key ***";
        String destBucketName = "*** Target bucket name ***";
        String destObjectKey = "*** Target object key ***";

        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .build();

            // Initiate the multipart upload.
            InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(destBucketName, destObjectKey);
            InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResult = s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);

            // Get the object size to track the end of the copy operation.
            GetObjectMetadataRequest metadataRequest = new GetObjectMetadataRequest(sourceBucketName, sourceObjectKey);
            ObjectMetadata metadataResult = s3Client.getObjectMetadata(metadataRequest);
            long objectSize = metadataResult.getContentLength();

            // Copy the object using 5 MB parts.
            long partSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
            long bytePosition = 0;
            int partNum = 1;
            List<CopyPartResult> copyResponses = new ArrayList<CopyPartResult>();
            while (bytePosition < objectSize) {
                // The last part might be smaller than partSize, so check to make sure
                // that lastByte isn't beyond the end of the object.
                long lastByte = Math.min(bytePosition + partSize - 1, objectSize - 1);

                // Copy this part.
                CopyPartRequest copyRequest = new CopyPartRequest()
                        .withSourceBucketName(sourceBucketName)
                        .withSourceKey(sourceObjectKey)
                        .withDestinationBucketName(destBucketName)
                        .withDestinationKey(destObjectKey)
                        .withUploadId(initResult.getUploadId())
                        .withFirstByte(bytePosition)
                        .withLastByte(lastByte)
                        .withPartNumber(partNum++);
                copyResponses.add(s3Client.copyPart(copyRequest));
                bytePosition += partSize;
            }

            // Complete the upload request to concatenate all uploaded parts and make the copied object available.
            CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(
                    destBucketName,
                    destObjectKey,
                    initResult.getUploadId(),
                    getETags(copyResponses));
            s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(completeRequest);
            System.out.println("Multipart copy complete.");
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client  
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // This is a helper function to construct a list of ETags.
    private static List<PartETag> getETags(List<CopyPartResult> responses) {
        List<PartETag> etags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
        for (CopyPartResult response : responses) {
            etags.add(new PartETag(response.getPartNumber(), response.getETag()));
        }
        return etags;
    }
}
```

**For objects smaller than 5 GB, use the single-operation copy**

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyObjectSingleOperation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Regions clientRegion = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION;
        String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";
        String sourceKey = "*** Source object key *** ";
        String destinationKey = "*** Destination object key ***";

        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .build();

            // Copy the object into a new object in the same bucket.
            CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(bucketName, sourceKey, bucketName, destinationKey);
            s3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client  
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- In my current project i am using the multipart upload described above to upload upto 15GB files it does have project specific modifications. [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsUsingLLJavaMPUapi.html)